# Woocommerce product opengraph

Tags: wordpress, facebook, woocommerce, share, facebook-opengraph

I'm working on a woocommerce, and when I try to share a product, there is no img or description, just like the og tag are empties, but just a link to the shared post.

I tried several plugins like yoast or woo open graph, but it doesn't solve my problem.
Can you help, please?

There is a link to a product: http://promoto.fr/produit/rfz-edition-limitee/

Comment: try now i solved your problem. it is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this link for solve this problem in future

## just scrape again your link after changes

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpromoto.fr%2Fproduit%2Frfz-edition-limitee%2F